# Plugin "react" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.json" and "BaseConfig

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I need help how to fix that, when starting the server on react with `npm start`

```
Failed to compile.
[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.json" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\Louda\Desktop\country-population\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
ERROR in [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.json" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\Louda\Desktop\country-population\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I want to resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict in the casing
C:\Users\Jalloh|desktop\reactapp\test.... whereas the nodemodules is looking for C:\Users\Jalloh|Desktop\Reactapp\test....
This is a windows specific problem, and previously react would have run the app regardless of this difference. Not anymore it seems.
The solution I used was to locate the folder and open with code; that ensures that the path matches directly with what is stored in node modules
[Here is the link](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/issues/4186)